# Adding 2 Letter Values Together?

Tags: python

I am currently attempting to encrypt with a keyword. I have taken the user input and the keyword input and got the values of each letter in the alphabet. (a=1, b=2, c=3 etc.) I now need to add these 2 values together. As I have used a while loop in my code to take each letter and take the value I cannot take each individual value and add it. Can someone give me a point in the right direction on how to add each value?
Thanks.

```
def keyEnc():
    alpha = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
    gcselist = ['g','c','s','e']
    code = input("Please enter the word you would like to encrypt: ")
    print("User's word is " + code)
    print("The number of letters in the code is: ")
    print(len(code))
    x=0
    while x < len(code):
        currLetterA=code[x]
        print("Letter: ",currLetterA)
        myii=alpha.index(currLetterA)
        myii=myii+1
        print("The Value Is: ",myii)
        x=x+1
#############################################################################################
    key = input("Please enter the keyword you would like to encrypt your word by: ")
    x=0
    while x < len(key):
        currLetter=key[x]
        print("Letter: ",currLetter)
        myi=alpha.index(currLetter)
        myi=myi+1
        print("The Value Is: ",myi)
        finWord = myi+myii
        print(finWord)
        x=x+1
keyEnc()
```

Comment: Note that this is not a reversible cipher! Either way it's probably better to use `ord` than to try and index each letter yourself.

Comment: I am quite new to python, but I was thinking if I can get the values of each then I can just finWord=(myi+myii+1)

Comment: I will look intto using the ord function. Thanks for the tip Adam.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your function. Can you give example EXPECTED input and output?

Comment: Ok so if you enter Adam as the main word and the keyword you enter is Code. It will take A which is 1 in the alphabet and C which is 3. I then need some hints on how to add the 1 and 3. I am finding it hard because it is in a while loop not individually being put in a variable if you see what I mean! Sorry if I am not very clear!

Comment: Please edit it into your question so future readers understand too :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to do this:

```
cleartext:  somewords = 19 15 13  5 23 15 18  4 19
key:        something = 19 15 13  5 20  8  9 14  7
                       ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
ciphertext:             38 30 26 10 43 23 27 18 26
```

Is that right? In which case you'll need a LIST of numbers, not just one output. Also make note that if your cleartext and key aren't exactly the same length, this isn't going to work. Imagine:

```
cleartext:  somewords = 19 15 13  5 23 15 18  4 19
key:        banana    =  2  1 14  1 14  1
                       ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
ciphertext:             21 16 27  6 37 16  ?  ?  ?
```

or

```
cleartext:  somewords     = 19 15 13  5 23 15 18  4 19
key:        bananahammock =  2  1 14  1 14  1  8  1 13 13 15  3 11
                           ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
ciphertext:                 21 16 27  6 37 16 36  5 32  ?  ?  ?  ?
```

However under those circumstances, it looks like you'll want this instead:

```
def key_enc():
    cleartext_word = input("Enter the word you want to encrypt: ")
    key = input("Enter the word you want as a key: ")
    if len(cleartext_word) != len(key):
        # I'm not sure how to handle this, so that's your design decision
        # but possibly just:
        raise ValueError("Clear text and key must have equal length")
    result = list()
    def lookup_letter(letter):
        """Helper function to return a proper index.

        a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, ..."""

        return ord(letter) - 96

    for letter, key_letter in zip(cleartext_word, key):
        result.append(lookup_letter(letter) + lookup_letter(key_letter))

    return result
```

The use of `zip` here is the key that you're missing. You don't TECHNICALLY need to do this, you could just use a `while` loop like you do in your code by doing:

```
def key_enc():
    # prompt for the cleartext_word and key as above
    result = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(cleartext_word): # which MUST BE EQUAL TO len(key)
        clear_letter = cleartext_word[i]
        key_letter = key[i]
        result_letter = ord(clear_letter)-96 + ord(key_letter)-96
        result.append(result_letter)
```

But it's harder to read that way.

And speaking of hard to read, essentially your whole function is:

```
result = list(map(lambda letters: sum(map(ord,letters))-192, zip(cleartext_word, key_word)))
# YUCK!!!
```

Comment: Ok bud. Thanks for the help I really appreciate it!